# How to clear and set textbox, checkbox and dropdownlist in nopcommerce using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, nopcommerce

Hello I have a view as below

```
<table class="adminContent">
    <tr>
        <td class="adminTitle">
            @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.Published)
        </td>
        <td class="adminData">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Published)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Published)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="adminTitle">
            @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.SearchCategoryId)
        </td>
        <td class="adminData">
            @Html.DropDownList("SearchCategoryId", Model.AvailableCategories)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="adminTitle">
            @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.Price)
        </td>
        <td class="adminData">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Price)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried to set the price in javascript like that

```
$('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.Price)').val('3333');
```

but it didnot reflect in the view also I need to reset the dropdownlist to use the 'All' option and to reset the checkbox

Comment: `#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.Price)` is server side code that evaluates to an html control. Using that as your jquery selector certainly won't work. You need to find out the actual id of your element. Either look at the resulting html markup, or hardcode it yourself on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default nopCommerce uses Telerik NumericTextBox. You cannot use jQuery "val" functiona to set its values. You did not spcify your nopCommerce version, so I presume you're using verion 3.30. It uses KendoUI (previously it used Telerik MVC Extensions). You can fidn it API [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/numerictextbox/api.html). It demonstrates how to set values for NumericTextBox

Answer (score 0):

The code you're showing is correct. That's the intended use of `FieldIdFor`, so the problem should be in the code you're not showing.

My first recommendation is to check the browser's console for errors and set a break-point with `debugger;`

To continue with this question you should give some more information about the context, for instance:

- The javascript code that completes the block.
- A sample of the rendered html code.

Comment: the code is fine and it's working but the value which I set is not shown in the page

Comment: So you know that the code works, that's good. Then you need to show something more to be able to find what does not work. For instance, have you already taken a look to the actual html markup? Maybe you're using template for the control that doesn't render the proper id... maybe you are executing jquery calls before the DOM is ready...